# App install failed - new target sandbox 1 is incompatible with previous value of 2

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I'm getting this error when trying to install the installed app on a device with the instant app installed. I've set targetSandboxVersion as 2 for both the instant and installed app but still get this error. What could be the issue?

I checked the apk manifests, there's the targetSandboxVersion attribute in the application tag for both the apps but only the instant app apk has the targetSandboxVersion attribute in the manifest tag also. Sharing in case it is helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it working.

Had to add
`android:targetSandboxVersion="2"` in the manifest tag instead of the application tag.

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: The app is immediately crashing when I am trying to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Android Settings on the device/emulator, go to Apps, scroll to your app and tap, then tap "Clear app" to remove the existing app with android:targetSandboxVersion="2". Then you can deploy your debug/prod version of your app with android:targetSandboxVersion="1" (the default value is "1" if you don't specify it explicitly).